# Problem trying to get information using Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm trying to get a hero by his name with the next method in the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/buscar/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Heroe>> findHeroByName(@RequestParam String name) {
        List<Heroe> heroes = heroesRepository.findByName(name);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(heroes, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

But when I use POSTMAN to get the information with the next line:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/heroes/buscar?name=Pisicola
```

It shows me this:

```
{
    "cause": {
        "cause": null,
        "message": "For input string: \"buscar\""
    },
    "message": "Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value [buscar]"
}
```

Instead of the information of the Hero.

This is all the code I have related to the problem:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/heroes")
public class HeroController {

    @Autowired
    private HeroesRepository heroesRepository;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Heroe> createHeroe(@RequestBody Heroe heroe) {
        Heroe savedHeroe = heroesRepository.save(heroe);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedHeroe, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    public ResponseEntity<Heroe> getHeroeById(long id) {
        Heroe heroe = heroesRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(heroe, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/buscar/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Heroe>> findHeroByName(@RequestParam String name) {
        List<Heroe> heroes = heroesRepository.findByName(name);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(heroes, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    public ResponseEntity<Heroe> updateHeroe(long id, Heroe heroe) {
        Heroe updatedHeroe = heroesRepository.save(heroe);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedHeroe, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    public ResponseEntity<Heroe> deleteHeroe(long id) {
        heroesRepository.deleteById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface HeroesRepository extends JpaRepository<Heroe, Long> {

    List<Heroe> findByName(String name);

}
```

Comment: You have to call `http://localhost:8080/api/heroes/buscar/Pisicola` to hit the mentioned endpoint

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you are mixing the URL syntax for `PathVariable` and `RequestParameter`.

For `RequestParameter` should be:

```
@GetMapping("/buscar")
public ResponseEntity<List<Heroe>> findHeroByName(@RequestParam String name) {
    List<Heroe> heroes = heroesRepository.findByName(name);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(heroes, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/heroes/buscar?name=Pisicola
```

For `PathVariable` should be:

```
@GetMapping("/buscar/{name}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Heroe>> findHeroByName(@PathVariable String name) {
    List<Heroe> heroes = heroesRepository.findByName(name);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(heroes, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/heroes/buscar/Pisicola
```

EDIT: the above examples are valid but won't fix the issue. You are using the `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` and your repository is annotated with `@RepositoryRestResource`. This cause some endpoints to be generated automatically by Spring. One of them is `/api/heroes/{id}` which takes a long as a path variable. This cause the issue when you are calling it with a string: `/api/heroes/buscar` You should avoid ambiguity when defining endpoints on top of the generated ones.

Comment: I tried it before posting the problem, and none of both works :(
The same error message appears

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the error.
The problem was that I was declaring that the RequestMapping was "/api/heroes/", but I was declaring in the application.properties file that the context.path is "api".

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

So the change is from:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/heroes/")
```

to

```
@RequestMapping("/heroes/")
```